# Swift 4 Charts Can't set the ChartYAxis Domain with Negative Numbers

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm struggling with the modifiers in the Swift 4 Chart API. I'm attempting to make
a RuleMark Chart where some of the data are negative numbers.

When I set the chart domain to 0...whatever, the chart is presented, but the "bottom"
of the chart is above the minimum values. If I attempt to put a negative number in
the domain range, the code breaks. The diagnostics say "ambiguous use of operator '-'"

[image]

If I do not include a .chartYScale, the chart is correctly presented, but the Swift
assigned y scale values leave a lot of wasted empty space making the chart unfriendly.

[image]

I've tried many range/domain options but have been unsuccessful. I want to be able to
programmatically control the Y scale including a negative number range.

Here's the Chart view:

```
struct RuleChartStandard: View {

    let dataStore = DataStore.shared

    var body: some View {
        Chart(dataStore.dayInfoRecords) { dayInfo in
            RuleMark(
                x: .value("Date", dayInfo.dateString),
                yStart: .value("Temperature", dayInfo.high),
                yEnd: .value("Temperature", dayInfo.low)
            )
        }
        .frame(height: 500)
        .padding(.leading, 25)
        .chartYScale(domain: 0...125)//this works, but the scale is incorrect
        //.chartYScale(domain: -50...125)//this does not work
        
    }
}
```

And here is the helper dataStore file:

```
class DataStore: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = DataStore()
    @Published var dayInfoRecords: [DayInfo] = []

    init() {
        generateDayInfoRecords(number: 50)
    }//init

    func generateDayInfoRecords(number: Int) {
        for x in 0..<number {
            let di = DayInfo(date: generateDateForDayInfo(dayIndex: x), precipitation: Double.random(in: 0..<10), snowfall: Double.random(in: 0..<10), high: Double.random(in: 45..<110), low: Double.random(in: -30..<45))
            dayInfoRecords.append(di)
        }
    }//generate records

    func generateDateForDayInfo(dayIndex: Int) -> Date {
        var components = DateComponents()
        components.day = dayIndex + 1
        components.month = 1
        components.year = 2022
        let date = Calendar.current.date(from: components)
        return date ?? Date()
    }
}//class
```

Any guidance would be appreciated. Xcode 14.2, iOS 16.2

Comment: `.chartYScale(domain: -50...125)` works fine for me.

Comment: Ahhh. I'm guilty of the Preview focus. Your comment does work for me when I'm in a simulator or a device. It does not work for me in Preview. I should have thought of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit Joakim Danielson with pointing out that it is the Preview that is misbehaving. The negative number domain bottom works in a simulator or device.

And for others to take this further, you can specify the stride amount like this:

```
var yAxisValues: [Int] {
    stride(from: -30, to: 120, by: 10).map { $0 }
}
```

Then add the modifier to the Chart:

```
.chartYAxis {
    AxisMarks(values: yAxisValues)
}
```

[image]